# Config file not being loaded in game

Tags: league-of-legends

I have edited my config.ini file in C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\Config to set my left click to attack move click, based on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/1bo2nk/guide_to_easy_kiting_left_click_attack/) reddit post.

When I go into a game, none of my changes to the file work. When I look at the settings in game, it simply ignores the file completely. It is as if it doesn't look at the file unless it is edited in game. How can I force it to load the changes to the config file?

I have tried changes settings in game and saving them, in the hope that it would load the rest of the saved settings in the file, but this does not work.

Comment: I think you have forgotten a Link? `this reddit post`

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why no one will answer this question...

Comment: try commenting on the reddit post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is, it doesn't work anymore.

The long answer requires researching all the patches over the last 2 years (the age of the quoted post), and then figuring out when the INI options were changed/disabled.  I'll post this as an incomplete answer for now, but the 2 year old post is not reliable and you should look into newer tutorials.

EDIT:
Sometime around 2011 there seems to be some changes to how the INI was accessed.

http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=189212&page=1

But that's pretty old still, even older than your post, but it is only a reference that the client can and does change its way of accessing the INI files.

The LoL Wiki has more details:
http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Hotkeys_and_commands

But it also may not be 100% accurate.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I may just have to set it up through my mouse settings. I didn't want to, since I would have to switch modes just for League, but that seems like the simplest way.

Comment: Something like AutoHotKey can change your mouse keys to whatever you want and it can be setup to affect only LoL.  If you have some level of programming skill that is something worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a little tedious however it works I have tested it multiple times.**

1. Login and stay on the lol client window.
2. While the lol client is open (very important) open the lol config folder and delete "input.ini" and "PersistedSettings.json"
3. Copy an edited "input.ini" into the config folder and start a custom game to commit the settings on the server side.

For anyone who does not have the settings: [League Config](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rdMTCawLNVdJOHOpoGbYz19wyHqas9v0)

Both the default and left mouse click can be found there

**related to the question but not useful to the solution**

The reason why it was changed was so riot could track people who use multiple accounts, so keep that in mind before you use a friends account you could easily get them banned if you make these changes as they would check if it matches other users there is also another file in this folder

> C:\Riot Games\League of
> Legends\RADS\projects\lol_air_client\releases\0.0.1.187\deploy\preferences

that riot uses to track user configurations.

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like there's some kind of persistent setting file that needs to be deleted.](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/tips-tricks/9NET1rjr-cant-change-my-inputini-file) I don't know if this fix still works, since I can't check on it, but it apparently worked as of 6 months ago.

From the thread:

> Was having same problem
>   removed the "persisent setting" file. works fine now
>   no problems either

---

> I have the answers to your problem. You have to go into persistent settings and find the certain key your trying to change. such as in my case I had to change evtAttackMoveClick with the button I wanted to set it to and save. Input.ini no longer overides league systems. You have to change it through Persistent Settings. Hope this helped.